# Does a 64 bit packed structure contains a field set to specified value

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have an odd structure with 5 fields of bit length 12 and 4 boolean flags stored in the high bits. This all fits nicely into a 64 bit long, and as such they are stored as a 64 bit word array. What I want to do is search the array and find if any of the 12 bit fields are set to a given value.

I have tried the obvious solution of using bit shifts and masks, however this is a very hot function and needs to be optimized for speed. This led me to the [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ValueInWord) page containing a way to check for a byte in a word in very few operations. This makes me think it is possible to do something similar with the 12 bit fields, however I am struggling to find what constants I would replace the ones given on that page with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very versed in low level languages, but I'm in the mood to fiddle with some bits so I thought I'd give it a try.

POC: JS can't do 64bit longs, but we can check if we can adapt the algorithm to deal with 2x12bit fields + 8boolean flags (noise) in an 32bit (u)int.

The noise because the original algorithm. Dealt with exactly 4 bytes and no further bits, but neither 32 nor 64 can be divided by 12 so we need to ensure that these additional bits don't interfere. Or worse, get matched.

```js
function hasValue(x, n) { return hasZero(x ^ (0x001001 * n)); }
function hasZero(v) { return ((v - 0x001001) & ~(v) & 0x800800); }

function hex(v) { return "0x" + v.toString(16) }

// create a random value, 2x12bit fields plus 8 random flags.
var v = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x100000000);
console.log("value", hex(v));

// get the two fields
var a = v & 0xFFF;
console.log("check", hex(a), !!hasValue(v, a));
var b = (v >> 12) & 0xFFF;
console.log("check", hex(b), !!hasValue(v, b));

// brute force.
// check if any other value is matched.
// these should only return the 2 values from above.
for (var i = 0; i < 0x1000; ++i) {
  if (hasValue(v, i)) {
    console.log("matched", hex(i));
  }
}
```

extrapolating from this, your solution should be

```c
#define hasValue(x,n) hasZero(x ^ (0x001001001001001 * n))
#define hasZero(v) ((v - 0x001001001001001) & ~(v) & 0x800800800800800)
```

where all values are unsigned longs. *(sorry don't know if you somehow have to annotate any of these numbers)*

Comment: `hasZero(v)` will tell us `if v has a zero field` and it will mark the position of the right-most field that is zero (if any). However, it will not mark all the zero fields (if one wanted that).